# Silverlight clipping a string on mac

Tags: .net, silverlight, macos, silverlight-3.0

I am facing a very strange issue in my silverlight app on all browsers on mac but it is working perfectly in all windows browsers.

in my silverlight app there is a scenario in which I create a very long text string and then pass it to a wcf service which then saves the string in a text file server. the issue is that in mac every time string is clipped after about same location. but it is working perfectly fine in all browsers on windows.

btw in silverlight I am using string builder to build the string.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a font variation between the platforms? I've noticed the default system font seems slightly different between mac/pc - try setting the textblock font explicitly to Arial and testing again?

Comment: thanks for your response. the area where the string is clipped has nothing to do with textblock. see i am getting the string from the server and then updating it. 

of i just realized that maybe in mac my silverlight app is not getting complete string from the server. is it possible?